# SPSS Macro to run aggregate command in multiple data files

Tags: macros, spss

I want to run the following codes on multiple SPSS data files (instead of having to open each file and running the codes separately etc.) but not sure how to write the appropriate macro. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
sort cases by ID(A) TEST_ID(A).


If RESULT='Positive' RESULTS=1.
If RESULT='Negative' RESULTS=0.


AGGREGATE OUTFILE='C:\Desktop\\072013-aggregated.sav'
/PRESORTED
/BREAK=ID
/CLINIC=FIRST(CLINIC)
/SEX=FIRST(SEX)
/DOB=FIRST(DOB).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that sort of thing with macro, but you can do it with the SPSSINC PROCESS FILES extension command.  That requires the (free) Python Essentials.  Newer versions of Statistics include this command in the Essentials.  If it isn't in your version, you can download it.  The command includes traditional SPSS syntax and a dialog box interface.

The Python Essentials and a wide variety of extension commands are available via the SPSS Community website at www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral.

Answer (score 1):

I will disagree with @JKP. It is possible to do it with macro.

Please consider other option. Try to add all files in one file (ADD FILES command). Create file indicator using IN subcommand (see the ADD FILES documentation). Run the command on the combined file only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily iterate the files using macro like below in **SPSS statistics**:

```
***Defining the path.

DEFINE !Path() 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\' 
!ENDDEFINE.
***You can seperate output paths from input paths and make another macro like above.

DEFINE !agg_loc (!POS=!CMDEND) .
!DO !var !IN (!1)
GET FILE=!quote(!CONCAT(!unquote(!eval(!Path)),!var,".sav")).
DATASET NAME !var.
DATASET ACTIVATE !var.

sort cases by ID(A) TEST_ID(A).
If RESULT='Positive' RESULTS=1.
If RESULT='Negative' RESULTS=0.

AGGREGATE OUTFILE=!quote(!CONCAT(!unquote(!eval(!Path)),!var,"_output_",".sav"))
    /PRESORTED
    /BREAK=ID
    /CLINIC=FIRST(CLINIC)
    /SEX=FIRST(SEX)
    /DOB=FIRST(DOB).

!DOEND.
EXECUTE.
!ENDDEFINE.

***Calling the macro.

!agg_loc dsn_abc.  
!agg_loc dsn_xyz.

**Here dsn_abc,dsn_xyz are file names present at desktop , you can add more file names similarly if there are more files to be read and processed

**The outcome will present at desktop appended with _output_  , e.g dsn_abc_output_.sav is output for first processing and so on.
```